# In the latest 2.79 daily build, is it possible to convert the Bevel node's RGB normal maps to BW edge highlighters?

Tags: node-editor, normals

[image]

On the left is the normal map generated by the Bevel node. On the right is an unbeveled cube with the Bevel node in action. I wish to convert this to a BW map where The edges/gradients are highlighted and the rest isn't. Does anyone know if this can be achieved with more nodes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Final result and node setup:

[image: Final]

After many tryouts with complicated setups it seems that this effect could be easily achieved by using **Vector Math > Cross Product** from **Bevel > Normal** output and **Texture Coordinates > Normals**.

After this the most efficient way is to use **Color Ramp** to change softness/sharpness of the edges.

Comment: Here's a digital hug, please accept it.

Comment: Where is the Cross Product Node? I cannot find it

Comment: @MicroMachine I believe that would be a variant of the Vector Math node.